# PostgreSQL: How it is possible to place values inside a text formula

Tags: postgresql

I have conditional formulas in each row:

```
/* CREATE TABLE */
CREATE TABLE conditional_table(conditional VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO conditional_table(conditional)VALUES('(%{a}==2)&&(%{b}/ %{c}) <= 0.34');
INSERT INTO conditional_table(conditional)VALUES('(%{a}==2)&&(%{b} / %{c}) > 0.47');
INSERT INTO conditional_table(conditional)VALUES('((%{b} / %{c}) > 0.47)&&(%{a}==1)');
INSERT INTO conditional_table(conditional)VALUES('(%{a}==1)&&(%{b} / %{c}) > 0.39 && (%{b} / %{c}) <= 0.47');
INSERT INTO conditional_table(conditional)VALUES('(%{d}==1) || (%{d}==2)');
INSERT INTO conditional_table(conditional)VALUES('(%{a}==1)&&(%{b}/ %{c}) <= 0.39');
INSERT INTO conditional_table(conditional)VALUES('(%{a}==2)&&(%{b} / %{c}) > 0.39 && (%{b} / %{c}) <= 0.47');
INSERT INTO conditional_table(conditional)VALUES('(%{a}==2)&&(%{b} / %{c}) > 0.34 &&(%{b}/ %{c}) <= 0.39');
INSERT INTO conditional_table(conditional)VALUES('%{d}==3');
```

[image]

I want to create a function that instead of values a, b, c, d will place numbers and return another column with a True / False result.

Is there a way to insert numbers within a text and return a result of a calculation?

Comment: It might be possible if those where valid SQL expressions. But with a "made up" syntax, that can't b evaluated in SQL this seems extremely hard (if not impossible)

Comment: Maybe there is some way with replacing the existing syntax with a more appropriate for SQL?

Comment: Or you can write an UDF/extension which can provide a function that can be called from SQL to evaluate these formulas using some constant values.

Comment: Where do the values `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` come from? Why does the database need to place them in the text and do the calculation? Do this in your application.

Comment: @Bergi the values ```a,b,c,d``` will come as inputs from function parameters, the goal is to reduce calls to the server.

Comment: if this notation  `(%{d}==1) || (%{d}==2)` was more sql like e.g.  `case when %d = 1 or %d = 2 then 1 else 0 end`  then you might be able to use string replacements and then dynamic sql - but it seems absurdly ugly & complex (& make the server response less efficient)